# IE cache problems: how to automatically set auto refresh from server

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser

On my web form i have select field with data from server. And if i doing something i need set on IE F12->Cache->Always refresh from server
If no data in select field (expl) no been updated. So how turn on this option automatically on html code? Because users don't know nothing about this options.

Comment: Do you mean IE cache your response? if so, you can append the timestamps as parameter in the URL.

Comment: If i take value from select menu (value from db) then i submit a form but my value still in select menu (if Always refresh from server tick is off) if tick is on then fine

Comment: Have you resolved your issue? If not, were you using ajax requests?